# jQuery submit form calls a function with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    function checkEmail(email){
         jQuery.post('someroute.php',
              {email:eamil},
                  function(data){
                                         if(data==error){
                                                return false;
                                         }
              );
      return true;
}

jQuery('#myform').submit(function(){
// como code and at the momment this
var result true;
//then I check email
var email = ('#myemail').val();
result =  checkEmail(email);
return result;
});
```

The problem is this, a `checkEmail` function, first return true, and then return value `jQuery.post` function. Why?

I checked and in submit, first return true, and if you stop submit then you release that post return the value. Post works fine, but I don't understand why function `checkEmail` does not wait until post returns the value and goes on until the end to return true.

Comment: Your code is missing `}` and `})`. If you indent your code properly and pass a quick jshint you'll be able to catch these errors before even posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `jQuery.post()` function is an AJAX request, and the first A in AJAX stands for *asynchronous*. That's exactly what asynchronous is, it doesn't stop code execution while it waits for a response. It fires the request and then immediately moves on to any code after the line making the request, in this case your `return true` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Like Anthony Grist said. .post is an asynchronous call which means it doesn't wait to finish. 
I've looked up the .post method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). 
It's basicly a shortcut for .ajax. You're missing the fail method in here so I would say use the .ajax call.

```
var value = 1;
var handlerUrl = "someroute.php";

//Do the Ajax Call
jQuery.ajax(
{
   url: handlerUrl,
   data: { email:eamil },
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (data)
   {
   return true;
   },
   error: function (jxhr, msg, err)
   {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1727336 : Hi! You might want to edit your code and add the missing `}` and `});`. Here's a fix:

```
// enter code here
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    function checkEmail(email){
        jQuery.post('someroute.php', {email:eamil},
        function(data){
            if(data==error){
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```